# why the gateway to be bogon?

Tags: android, linux, networking, ip, gateway

I connect my Android phone with my PC through USB. And open the usb tether option on the phone.

So, there is a new remote NDIS network adapter displayed in the PC's network connections, and there is a rnndis0 IFface on the android.

I do the following configurations:
PC:      ip: 192.168.42.1 netmask: 255.255.255.0

Phone:   ip 192.168.42.2  netmask: 255.255.255.0

And when ping each other, both work ok.

But when I configure the default gateway of my phone to be the address of the PC, it failed.

```
busybox route add default gw 192.168.42.1
busybox route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         bogon           0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 rndis0
192.168.42.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 rndis0
```

can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: What is the output of $ ip route
on Android?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's marked as bogon as it is an address which should not appear in a routing table, ie a bogon route.

This is because it is a private network address.  It's only a warning though.

see http://packetlife.net/blog/2009/jan/21/whats-bogon/

Comment: You are right. It is just a warning for private network address.

Answer (score 0):

```
What is the output of

$ ip route
on Android?
```

SivlerZhao

Yesterday, I was unable to reproduce the problem.
Now, it reproduced.

```
busybox route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         bogon           0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 rndis0
192.168.137.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 rndis0
```

And the output of ip route is:

```
busybox ip route
default via 192.168.137.1 dev rndis0
192.168.137.0/24 dev rndis0  src 192.168.137.2
```

Actually, it works ok, but the "bogon" word apears